# What happens when a rocket explodes (specifically, the SpaceX CRS-7 mission)?

Tags: spacex

In [videos of the SpaceX CRS-7 explosion](https://youtu.be/WTVkhp0MxMc?t=2m22s) I've seen, it looks like the explosion vaporized the rocket, since no wreckage/debris made it more than a few feet downward -- tiny little things!

But the vaporization temp for aluminum is over 10,000 °C. RP-1 rocket fuel is kerosene, basically. So that doesn't seem to be sufficient to vaporize aliminium.

Also, I looked at many rockets exploding and the flames are always orange (kerosene). The SpaceX explosion is colorless. I also could not find any rocket explosions wherein NOTHING was left. So what happened in this incident?

Comment: This is not a question, unfortunately. Similarly, this question is also too opinion-based. Objectively, if you think SpaceX is faking their crashes, you might as well think that the moon landings were faked. Maybe with a heavy overhaul this could be put on Skeptics.SE

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is errant nonsense.

Comment: Closed as opinion-based, but that wasn't my choice. (See the above comment.)

Comment: Stop drinking the koolaid, Allancw. A conspiracy this large would have seen the light of day in, well, a day or so. There are several thousand employees at SpaceX alone, several thousand more at NASA, and several thousand more at SpaceX's commercial customers. SpaceX is not faking its successes or its failures. You can ask legitimate questions here such as "Why do the SpaceX rockets have plumes shooting upwards?" OTOH, we do not tolerate errant nonsense here. Skeptics.SE does (to some extent).

Comment: @DavidHammen: Not that it really matters, but I believe the spelling is "arrant" for this phrase.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Ouch! You are correct. (Although errant also applies in this case.)

Comment: I am voting to reopen, because such questions deserve answer and not closure. Although the video should be edited to not distribute conspiracy theories any more. As a pure factual question, it should be okay!

Comment: @Allancw We are not so bad guys as it seems! But edit out all the conteos, make it a purely factual question. So: "Why there no poof remained after that SpaceX explosion?" And then, include the video. (Without the conteos!) And you will get your answers.

Comment: @JavaScriptCoder I see it a *very bad direction* if a question can be closed because the OP *might* believe some crap.

Comment: @peterh well the main thing is that there are no questions per se in the body: they are all arguments. (except for one rhetorical one which isn't meant to be answered)

Comment: I've removed the nonsense from the question to see if it's salvageable like this. Would be better with some links to the videos OP is referring to.

Comment: I want to know how a rocket like a Falcon 9 could vaporize in an explosion. It seems the launch on May 11 did exactly that. I'm sorry if pointing this out somehow equals a 'conspiracy theory,' but everyone here knows my question is a question (Orwell would agree.) What happened when the Falcon 9 on May 11 blew up, leaving no debris? I don't know how else to word the question. 'Stop drinking the kool aid,' I'm told. Who is drinking kool aid here when a 'miracle' seems to have happened and no one wants to deal with it?

Comment: Hold on. I just realized that my question was re-worded. I'd forgotten how I'd phrased it. I appreciate your taking the time to do that and I have no problem with the re-wording. Yes, my 'question' may have been phrased incorrectly but in substance it was obvious what the 'question' was. Again, thanks! Looking forward to any answers...

Comment: Sorry, a correction to the above. I meant to say 'August, 2015 launch,' not 'May 11'... I now realize I should have worded my question as you have done; I thought it would be more 'honest' to say what was on my mind. You guys are very smart: Two possibilities. One, you easily show that I'm a fool, and do so without fallacies. Or, Two, YOU guys learn something. Win-win. But I forgot how touchy some folks can be about their 'base' world views. Me, I just want to learn how the world really works.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open considering the revision; removing down vote as well.

Comment: Uh oh, uhoh! ;)

Comment: The August 2015 launch is the AMOS 6 mission, which exploded on the pad in a pre-launch test. Here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BgJEXQkjNQ

Comment: Turns out we were both wrong. My link was to the 'mishap' on June 28, 2015 (not August). Yours was in September of 2016, I believe. Thanks for that link, which I hadn't seen before; it was instructive. You will notice the red-orange color of the blast, typical of kerosene-base fuel. The June, 2015 explosion was, of course, colorless, which is (partially) my point. I also noticed that I can 'make' a similar explosion with Final Cut. What is hard is making falling debris. I think you get my point. I'm still hoping for you tech guys to analyze the explosion (June 28, 2015), showing it as real.

Comment: It's a perfectly valid question (phrased in an odd manner) deserving an answer ...

Comment: I've taken the liberty of targeting the question at CRS-7 rather than AMOS 6, and linking to video of the explosion. I've also reversed my downvote. Without the presumption of fakery it's an interesting question.

Comment: @RussellBorogove In the case of CRS-7, the rocket did not break up completely, the capsule transmitted telemetry until it impacted the ocean.... so the edit somewhat invalidates the premise of the question (nothing at all comes down). It seems quite hard to make this question reasonable. Sceptics.SE might be better suited for it.

Comment: @Polygnome Telemetry isn't at all apparent from the video, though. OP was explicitly referencing CRS-7 in the initial form of the post. The actual verbatim questions in the current form of the post: "what happens when a rocket explodes?" and "what happened in this incident?" aren't skeptics.se material at all.

Comment: @RussellBorogove I agree that *this* revision isn't something for sceptics anymore, the original however, was. I mentioned the telemetry because the capsule was intact until it impacted the ocean, while the body of the question claims " no wreckage/debris made it more than a few feet downward", which simply isn't true in this case.

Answer (score 10):

I don't have a definitive answer for the appearance of the explosion in this incident, but a few things are worth noting:

Note the appearance of the first-stage engine plumes at 2:22. Rather than the bright dense yellow column seen at liftoff, the low atmospheric pressure at the rocket's altitude allows the exhaust stream to rapidly expand into a relatively faint, tenuous cloud. The rocket is still producing about the same amount of thrust (maybe somewhat less than at liftoff to control g-loading on the structure), but the exhaust looks completely different from kerosene/LOX combustion at sea level.

The incident occurred when a small high-pressure helium tank contained within the second-stage liquid oxygen tank broke loose, overpressurizing and rupturing the tank, [as described in this Q/A](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9686/what-went-wrong-with-the-crs-7-launch). I assume the initial white cloud at around 2:30 is just oxygen release.

Once the second stage starts to come apart, kerosene is released as well, and you can see characteristic yellow-orange kerosene flame inside the white cloud at about 2:32 in the video.

You can see small pieces of the upper stage falling away from the rocket between 2:32 and 2:36 until the rocket comes apart completely. Two things to keep in mind here: one, the first stage is near the end of its burn here, and so largely empty of fuel; two, to get good combustion between kerosene and oxygen, you have to thoroughly mix the two. Starting with two separate "balls" of liquid venting into extremely thin air, you won't get good mixing; any combustion that does occur where the clouds meet will tend to spread the kerosene and oxygen further away from each other, so the majority of the remaining first-stage propellants just won't get burned here. That's why you don't see a large orange fireball here -- again, other rocket explosions you're comparing this to are probably low-altitude incidents, where atmospheric pressure is keeping the propellants from dispersing quickly. Additionally, according to the Q/A linked above, the flight termination system was activated, "unzipping" the tanks in a way that was intended specifically to minimize the force of an explosion.

At 2:38 you see several distinct pieces of the rocket. To me it looks like possibly 1/4 of the entire skin of the rocket is visible in pieces at that point -- remember that a rocket like Falcon 9 is basically a thin metal skin wrapped around fuel, not a solid piece of metal. So the big open question for me is where the rest of the metal went, but if it was being ripped into small pieces at about 2:37, those pieces could easily have gone out of frame while concealed in the vapor cloud.

Finally, I'm going to address the way your question here was initially framed. On this site we get a fair number of conspiracy theorists -- mostly moon landing deniers, but a few other kinds as well. I can't speak for the other regulars on the site, but they make me very angry; they waste our time and mental effort, and for the most part they aren't interested in truth as much as they're interested in propping up a paranoid world view. I'm happy to address any question posed in the frame of "I don't understand some phenomenon", but the same essential question framed as "This phenomenon proves some conspiracy theory" will never find a good reception here.

In this case, the idea that SpaceX would fake a launch accident simply makes no sense at all. They are still a young company trying to build a reputation for reliability; losing a rocket with a NASA payload hurts them very badly. Hundreds or thousands of people saw a rocket lift off, bound for the International Space Station. That rocket's payload never reached its destination, but it must have gone somewhere. In general, [the simplest explanation for a phenomenon is, most likely, the correct one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor), while extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence. "The rocket exploded as rockets sometimes do" is a very simple explanation, and "SpaceX faked a lost rocket" requires an awful lot of justification.

Comment: +1, space program deniers are calling me and all my former colleagues liars, and I take that very personally indeed.

Comment: I wouldn't want to jump in and unnecessarily edit such a solid answer. But one additional thought that occurred to me on the topic of debris -- the asker may want to recall that the rocket is 230' tall, and being viewed from a camera many miles away. That we can see the rocket doesn't mean we can see the parts of the rocket when it comes a part at that distance.

Comment: We can see lots of debris at 2:37-2:40.

Comment: There was enough debris to show up on radar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIOoZ9pz0r4